# FFmpeg video metadata change

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to change the video stream metadata. See (Change This Metadata) below. I can change the title of the movie ok but not any others. What is the ffmpeg line to change this.

This line below changes "Title Of The Movie" only

ffmpeg -i Input.mkv -metadata title="New Title" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy Output.mkv

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Input.mkv':
Metadata:
title           : Title Of The Movie
encoder         : libebml v1.2.3 + libmatroska v1.3.0
creation_time   : 2014-08-02 12:58:30
Duration: 02:15:54.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8177 kb/s
Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 208.666778
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 01
Chapter #0.1: start 208.666778, end 811.727578
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 02
Chapter #0.2: start 811.727578, end 1077.868444
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 03
Chapter #0.3: start 1077.868444, end 1345.302289
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 04
Chapter #0.4: start 1345.302289, end 2000.415067
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 05
Chapter #0.5: start 2000.415067, end 2487.276444
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 06
Chapter #0.6: start 2487.276444, end 3097.302533
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 07
Chapter #0.7: start 3097.302533, end 3503.958778
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 08
Chapter #0.8: start 3503.958778, end 4060.347956
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 09
Chapter #0.9: start 4060.347956, end 4582.202622
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 10
Chapter #0.10: start 4582.202622, end 5083.078000
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 11
Chapter #0.11: start 5083.078000, end 5537.698822
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 12
Chapter #0.12: start 5537.698822, end 5826.612444
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 13
Chapter #0.13: start 5826.612444, end 6553.088200
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 14
Chapter #0.14: start 6553.088200, end 6903.730156
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 15
Chapter #0.15: start 6903.730156, end 7271.055444
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 16
Chapter #0.16: start 7271.055444, end 7582.241333
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 17
Chapter #0.17: start 7582.241333, end 8153.937444
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 18
Chapter #0.18: start 8153.937444, end 8154.208000
Metadata:
  title           : Chapter 19
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  title           : Change This Metadata
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  title           : Eng
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default)
Metadata:
  title           : Eng
```

Answer (score 10):

Ok I have found this which works:

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mkv -metadata:s:v:0 title="H264 Video" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy Output.mkv
```

I think `:s:v:0` some of the comments stands for:

:v = Video stream
:0 = Use first video stream

Answer (score 7):

This does the trick:

```
ffmpeg -i "in.m4v" -metadata title="New Title" -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "out.m4v"
```

Comment: This works. It seems that the metadata need to be given before the video/audio parameters

Answer (score -4):

Open windows explorer

Locate and hight light the files, you want to change

select multiple tracks, press on the control key in your keyboard and then click the tracks that you want to change

Right click on the files, chose property and then summary 
click on the value field of a property that you want to modify for example title.