# Set video's metadata by Python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, metadata

I need to upload the video to Google Photos. There is no way to set a date in request, only by metadata. I made a test by setting the date manually (windows, file options) and it works in Google Photos. So, I don't understand how to set it by Python. I found the needed value, but I can't set it.

```
import ffmpeg

file_path = r"test.MP4"
vid = ffmpeg.probe(file_path)

vid['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time']
```

Result `'2020-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z'`

I tried `vid['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time'] = '2015-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z'`

But nothing changes. Please help.

Note that this is about the video file's metadata, NOT WINDOWS DATA

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666879) is how to do it in FFmpeg. `-metadata` is an output option, so look into how to set output stream option in `ffmpeg-python`

Answer (score 2):

We can't simply modify the tag.
For adding/changing a tag using FFmpeg, we have to create a new video file that may be identical to the original file, but has the modified tag.

I found an example using FFmpeg CLI in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534938/4926757).

Command line example:
`ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -metadata creation_time="2015-10-21 07:28:00" -map 0 -c copy out.mp4`.

The equivalent ffmpeg-python code is:

```
ffmpeg.input('in.mp4').output('out.mp4', metadata='creation_time=2015-10-21 07:28:00', map=0, c='copy').overwrite_output().run()
```

- `metadata='creation_time=2015-10-21 07:28:00'` - adds the tag `creation_time` with tag value `2015-10-21 07:28:00`.
- `map=0` - maps all streams and data from the input `in.mp4` to the output `out.mp4`.
- `c='copy'` - copy all the streams (video, audio, subtitles...) from `in.mp4` to `out.mp4` without re-encoding.

As commented by Kesh, `metadata` is an output option, so we have to place it in `.output(...)`.

---

Testing:

- Create synthetic video file `in.mp4` (for testing):

  ```
   ffmpeg.input('testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10', f='lavfi').output('in.mp4').overwrite_output().run()
  ```
- Use `ffmpeg.probe` for checking the value of `creation_time` of `in.mp4`:

  ```
   p = ffmpeg.probe('in.mp4')
   if 'creation_time' in p['streams'][0]['tags']:
       print(p['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time'])  # Not enter here, because in.mp4 has no 'creation_time' tag.
  ```
- Adding `creation_time` tag with value `2015-10-21 07:28:00` to `in.mp4`, creating a new file `out.mp4`:

  ```
   ffmpeg.input('in.mp4').output('out.mp4', metadata='creation_time=2015-10-21 07:28:00', map=0, c='copy').overwrite_output().run()
  ```
- Use `ffmpeg.probe` for checking the value of `creation_time` of `in.mp4`:

  ```
   p = ffmpeg.probe('out.mp4')
   print(p['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time'])  # Prints: 2015-10-21T04:28:00.000000Z
  ```

---

Complete sample (testing the modification of existing tag):

```
import ffmpeg

# ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 in.mp4
ffmpeg.input('testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10', f='lavfi').output('in.mp4').overwrite_output().run()

# ffprobe -print_format json -show_format in.mp4
p = ffmpeg.probe('in.mp4')

if 'creation_time' in p['streams'][0]['tags']:
    print(p['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time'])  # Not enter here, because in.mp4 has no 'creation_time' tag.

# ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -metadata creation_time="2020-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z" -map 0 -c copy test.mp4
ffmpeg.input('in.mp4').output('test.mp4', metadata='creation_time=2020-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z', map=0, c='copy').overwrite_output().run()

# ffprobe -print_format json -show_format test.mp4
p = ffmpeg.probe('test.mp4')
print(p['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time'])  # Prints: 2020-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z
    
# ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -metadata creation_time="2015-10-21 07:28:00" -map 0 -c copy out.mp4
ffmpeg.input('test.mp4').output('out.mp4', metadata='creation_time=2015-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z', map=0, c='copy').overwrite_output().run()

# ffprobe -print_format json -show_format out.mp4
p = ffmpeg.probe('out.mp4')
print(p['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time'])  # Prints: 2015-11-01T20:07:09.000000Z
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to write metadata with `ffmpeg,` as far as I know. Have you checked out [mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but I haven't found the needed value. KeyError: 'creation_time'